# Order of wl_display_dispatch and wl_display_roundtrip call

Tags: x11, wayland, qtwayland

I am trying to make sense of which one should be called before and which one later between wl_display_dispatch and wl_display_roundtrip.  I have seen both order so wondering which one is correct.

```
1st order:

    wl_display_get_registry(display); wl_registry_add_listener() // this call is just informational
    wl_display_dispatch();
    wl_display_roundtrip();
```

what i think :  wl_display_dispatch() will read and dispatch events from display fd, whatever is sent by server but in between server might be still processing requests and for brief time fd might be empty.
wl_display_dispatch returns assuming all events are dispatched. Then wl_display_roundtrip() is called and will block until server has processed all request and put then in event queue. So after this, event queue still has pending events, but there is no call to wl_display_dispatch(). How those pending events will be dispatched ? Is that wl_display_dispatch() wait for server to process all events and then dispatch all events?

```
2nd order:

    wl_display_get_registry(display); wl_registry_add_listener() // this call is just informational
    wl_display_roundtrip();
    wl_display_dispatch();
```

In this case, wl_display_roundtrip() wait for server to process all events and put them in event queue, So once this return we can assume all events sent from server are available in queue. Then wl_display_dispatch() is called which will dispatch all pending events.

Order 2nd looks correct and logical to me, as there is no chance of leftover pending events in queue. but I have seen Order 1st in may places including in weston client examples code so I am confused whats the correct order of calling.

It would be great if someone could clarify here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

2nd order is correct.
client can't do much without getting proxy(handle for global object). what i mean is client can send request by binding to the global object advertised by server so for this client has to block until all global object are bind in registry listener callback.

for example for client to create surface you need to bind wl_compositor interface then to shell interface to give role and then shm(for share memory) and so on.wl_display_dispatch cannot guaranty all the events are processed if your lucky it may dispatch all events too but cannot guarantee every-time. so you should use wl_display_roundtrip for registry at-least.